# Getting Form2 variable to Form1 (User text input in TextBox)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

The plan:
I want to ask the user with second Form2 to input some text.
When this Form2 is closed, i want to display the input text in a textbox on Form1...

On a button event, on Form2 i can reach Form1's textbox:

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

And:

```
form1.myText = "Test Name";
```

And then i close Form2:

```
this.Close();
```

But the value "Test Name" does not appear in form1's textbox...
I don't get an error.

Comment: The eternal Winforms question.  Add `form1.Show();`  You can't learn object-oriented programming with trial and error.  Use a book or a class to learn the basics.

Comment: @HansPassant Assuming he said *But the value "Test Name" does not appear in form1's textbox*, I figured the form did show up. Otherwise, you are probably right.

Comment: @Nomistake Then you should not create a new one!

Comment: @DionV. Ok, i did this to access the textbox in form1, but i guess this isnt the rigth approach... Thank you

Comment: @HansPassant "You can't learn object-oriented programming with trial and error. Use a book or a class to learn the basics"
Waaaauw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `new Form1()`, then new instance of `Form1` is created. You have two objects of `Form1`. That's why your code doesn't work.

If you want to make it fast, add `Form1` as a variable to `Form2` class.

```
public Form1 form1;
```

Then you can set it just before showing `Form2`.

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.form1 = this;
form2.Show();
```

Remember to remove this part: `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`.

Now your code should work.

Comment: Ok, tested it on a new solution.
Now i will try to implement it on the existing one... thank you

Comment: Sure. When you launch your app Form1 is created. Form2 doesn't know about Form1 existence. That's why I set `form2.form1 = this`. `this` means Form1 that is created.

Answer (score 0):

Create event handler on Form2 and when open Form2 from Form1 hook on this event. In form2 fire this event with your own eventargs which contains text which u need to show in Form1.

Another solution is Action. Create property Action in Form2 and when opened Form2 set this action. When Form2 is closed fire this action like `_action.Invoke(textWhichUneed);`

Answer (score -1):

You should make assign value before close. For example

```
form1.myText = "Test Name";
this.Close();
```

Also form1 shouldn't be created, but passed. How do you pass form1 into form2?

Comment: This is what i did and describe :-)

Comment: how do you get access to form1?

Comment: Can you say or give a good link how to pass it?
I created a new, and thats causing the problem